# C# Linq EF Core 6.0 Retrieve a secondary list of objects as part of an include only if it isn't null

Tags: c#, database, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use Linq to get a list of objects.  Part of each of these objects is a potential list of child objects that are of the same type, if there is no list then it is null.  I'm trying to figure out how to get this secondary list to be returned with each of my main objects.

Here is my primary class.  There could be more than one display at a specific location, and I want to be able to see and link back to the other displays that share the location. If it is the only display, then I set Group to null, so no group is created for just a single display.

```
public class Display
{
    public int DisplayId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } = null!;
    public int? DisplayGroupId { get; set; }
    //Displays At Same Location
    public DisplayGroup? DisplayGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my middle table that I'm using to show which displays are at the same location.

```
public class DisplayGroup
{
    public int DisplayGroupId { get; set; }
    public List<Display> Displays { get; set; } = null!;

}
```

Here is one, what I thought was the best, example of what I have tried to get the list. Unfortunately, when I run through this, I get an exception `'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll`

```
List<Display> list = await _context.Displays.AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.DisplayGroup)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Displays)
                .ToListAsync();
return list;
```

After reading in various places, including on StackOverflow, I have not been able to get an answer that actually returns what I'm looking for.

Sorry if I failed to provide all that is needed to help trouble shoot my question, this is my first time asking.  If more info is needed, I can post back.
Thank you in advanced for any help.

What I'm hoping to get as a result is something like this:

| Display | Display at same location |
| --- | --- |
| DisplayA | DisplayB / DisplayC / DisplayE |
| DisplayB | DisplayA / DisplayC / DisplayE |
| DisplayC | DisplayA / DisplayB / DisplayE |
| DisplayD | N/A |
| DisplayE | DisplayA / DisplayB / DisplayC |
| DisplayF | DisplayG |
| DisplayG | DisplayF |

Edit:
What I'm looking for is to get a `List<Display>` that would contain all of the displays I have, in the example above DisplayA-DisplayG, but then within each display object access the `DisplayGroup.Displays`. Something like:

```
List<Display> list = SomeFunctionToGetAnInitialListOfDisplays();
foreach(Display mainDisplay in list)
{
    foreach(Display secondaryDisplay in mainDisplay.DisplayGroup.Displays)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(secondaryDisplay.DisplayId);
        Console.WriteLine(secondaryDisplay.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

I'm hoping to accomplish this in one set of Linq statements so that I only have to make one call to the Database instead of making a call to the database for every display in the main list.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want all the displays in the group for a particular display? *"Where I can click on any of the above display name to go to a page related to them."* is unclear...

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by "click on" etc. but this answer should solve the problem that I think you have tried to articulate.

Say you have a flat list of `Display` objects and for any particular object, you would like to grab a list of all the other `Display` objects within the same group. Then:

```cs
List<Display> getDisplayGroupForDisplay(int displayId) {
    List<Display>? displays = await _context.Displays.First(x => x.displayId == displayId).DisplayGroup?.Displays;
    return displays != null ? displays : new List<Display>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This is an option I was beginning to look at, but I was hoping to get it all in one call to the database.  If I get a list of Displays that is 100, then I would have to make another 100 calls to the db to get all of their grouped displays. Also what I meant by "Click on" was if this was a webpage I could embed a link in the list for each display to have a page based on their ids.